# Views field for content access?

Tags: views, users

I'm building a membership site and I'm trying to find the best way to tease content that's only available to subscribers but show it in the same view as content available to all.

I'm currently using the content access module and while I'm able to generate the view that includes both open and restricted content I need a way to attach a lock icon to the rows who have restricted access. My thought was to have the view output the content access permission as a field but content access doesn't appear to have anything currently exposed to views.

Has anyone done something like this before? I'm open to using a different access control module as long as I can set permissions on a per-node basis.

Comment: Does the view attach a container class for the restricted vs open content that you could use to add an icon with css?

Comment: Is the content type of restricted access different from the allowed to all?

Comment: @thumbson: That's what I'm trying to do but I can't seem to expose the access status to the view itself

Comment: @no sssweat: no they're the same content type and they have various permissions set via the content access module

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this in a while (2 years), but it did what you described back then!

https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions